# How to display data on another website via widget like facebook like box?

Tags: php, xml, rss, export, widget

I have a RSS feed generated by my server ( for example : http://www.seek-team.com/en/teams/counter-strike-source/feed/ )

and I want the feed (only the title of the feed + article + links of course ;)) to be displayed on other website (other domains) as a widget like facebook like box or similar (i took facebook for example because it's very easy to set-up (copy, paste, that's all).

For a similar problem, i used JSON-P , but it's too difficult for the user to understand the jquery function to decode and display JSON-P than using a simple javascript inclusion.

**What would you recommand ? Where would you start ?**

**Do you have any "how-to" to achieve this project with only one contraint : it must be installed via a javascript to avoid complexity**

Thanks.

Comment: Only the title of the feed or only the title of the article?

Comment: both ;) title of the feed + title of the articles + links of course

Comment: Javascript to avoid complexity? iframe's would be my choice, total control.

Comment: and how to do that please ? what do i need for an iframe in this context to generate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then your best bet is to put your feed in to feedburner, then use something like the buzzBoost widget.  It lets you control number of entries, the title of the whole widget, display the date, the author part of the content, none of the content, open in new window or same window etc.

example javascript to embed...

```
<script src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/blah?format=sigpro" type="text/javascript" ></script><noscript><p>Subscribe to RSS headline updates from: <a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/blah"></a><br/>Powered by FeedBurner</p> </noscript>
```

Answer (score 1):

Magpie (http://magpierss.sourceforge.net/) is a simple RSS feed reader for PHP that works well.  From there, you could build simple code to encapsulate it into the "widget" format you're looking for.